# asp.net mvc Comparing password using SCrypt

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, scrypt

i'm using [SCrypt](https://github.com/viniciuschiele/Scrypt)

installed it using nuget manager.

then,

at the top before every action:

```
ScryptEncoder encoder = new ScryptEncoder();
```

register action:

```
tblUser userItems = new tblUser();
string hashedPassword = encoder.Encode("mainObject.Password");
useritems.emailadd = mainObject.emailadd;
userItems.password = hashedPassword;

db.tblUsers.Add(userItems);
db.SaveChanges();
```

it does work, password saved in database is hashed.

login action:

```
var x = th.tblUsers.Where(a => a.emailadd.Equals(ms.Email)).First();
bool areEquals = encoder.Compare("ms.Password", x.password.ToString());
var dataItem = th.tblUsers.Where(a => a.emailadd.Equals(ms.Email) && areEquals == true).First();
```

as i debug, the second line bool return false.
can't figure it out, how am i doing it wrong.

Comment: I suspect the encoded password & the compare password is different. - can you double check that?

Comment: @Immanuel you mean the one i input in login? if yes, then, yeah i've double checked many times, i'm typing it correctly

Comment: below code wit in `` works fine and return - true, only difference from your code "mainObject.Password" is same in both the places, 
`            string hashedPassword = encoder.Encode("mainObject.Password");
            bool areEquals = encoder.Compare("mainObject.Password", hashedPassword.ToString());
`
still if you see the issues, make sure the password text encoding is right & correct culture is used for the text

Comment: @Immanuel you mean to say, i need to hash the password in the login action? before doing comparing?

Comment: No, in code content you provided, the text "mainObject.Password" & "ms.Password" should be same and can not be different.

Comment: @Immanuel mainObject.Password is coming from input field from registration view and is being save into the database. ms.Password is coming from input field in login view.

Comment: So why are they in quotes here? That means you're using those strings, not the values from the named variables. Or was that a typo writing the question?

Comment: @silver01 you should clean up the code. What you posted until now shows an attempt to compare an unhashed string with a stored hash. This will always fail. You should probably change the code anyway. Instead of *loading* the user and then checking the hash, you can hash the input first and use that as a filter along with the email.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can't hash the input first as scrypt includes a randomly generated salt. You do need to compare the value against an existing hash as here, where it can take the salt from the hash.

Comment: @Rup so there's a nice way to find out if an account exists - measure the time to rejection. Quick rejection, the account doesn't exist. Slow rejection, the account exists but the password was wrong. That's explained in one of Troy Hunt's Pluralsight courses

Comment: @Rup yes upon debugging, whats comparing is the input value vs. the hashed value in db. that's is my problem. how do i code it. i'm just following whats said in SCrypts github. using encoder.compare(string, string)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, good point. I suppose you could mitigate that by running a hash on the supplied password anyway if you can't find the user, perhaps with a fixed salt so the missing user hash time is consistent. But this feels like something that's been properly solved already, so there must be ASP..NET Identity provider implementations out there to start from rather than starting from scratch like this.

Comment: I think the compare call is right, you just need to pass the variable ms.Password rather than the string "ms.Password": `areEquals = encoder.Compare(ms.Password, x.password.ToString());` Can you step into Scrypt Compare and check that the strings it's receiving look right? Why do you need the .ToString on the password value - it is stored as a string in the database, not a binary blob?

Comment: @Rup indeed. In fact, the linked project appears abandoned for 2 years.

Comment: @Rup bool areEquals = encoder.Compare(ms.Password, x.password); i've removed ToString() and double quote on ms.Password. what comparing here is, ms.Password: asdasd44 vs. x.password: "$s2$16384$8$1$MhL/jYIrc49xe/tl7psPN+Hf40UxKP0wKow/upq2Xrg=$7ai2KXSUglR1eh5aHRXlpqbRIHC8msQb0MTMc1g0+H8=" that is the hashed one that is stored in db. bool returns false

Comment: That's because you've made the same mistake with the variable name / string in the code that's creating the password hash. The hash matches `mainObject.Password`. Try logging in with that as your password.